# Randomized stopping times

Tags: stochastic-processes

On p. 75 of his Stochastic Calculus book, Michael Steele writes,
[image]

Here, $\tau$ is defined as the first time that a certain random walk leaves a certain random interval, and the subtlety is the randomness of the latter interval. Steele calls this a "randomized" stopping time, to distinguish it from stopping times defined in terms of first visit in a deterministic set. Is there a version of Doob's theorem that covers randomized stopping times?

Comment: Doob’s Theorem works just fine for randomized stopping times.

Comment: It's just a matter of convention - randomized stopping times can be considered as ordinary ones on a bigger state space